# Parse info from tables with Scrapy and XPath

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to extract attributes from a website with scrapy and xpath:

```
response.xpath('//section[@id="attributes"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/text()').extract()
```

The attributes are nested in the following way:

```
<section id="attributes">
<h5>Attributes</h5>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Attribute 1</td>
                    <td>Value 1</td>
                </tr>           
                <tr>
                    <td>Attriburte 2</td>
                    <td>Value 2</td>
                </tr>
```

There are two problems associated with this:

1. Get the content of the td elements (the XPath command will return[])
2. Once the `td` is retrieved, I need to get the pairing somehow. e.g.: "Attribute 1" = "Value 1"

I am new to phyton and scrapy, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should try to remove `tbody` tag from XPath as usually it's not in page source.

You can update your code as below:

```
cells = response.xpath('//section[@id="attributes"]/div/table//tr/td/text()').extract()
att_values = [{first: second} for first, second in zip(cells[::2], cells[1::2])]
```

You will get list of attribute-value pairs:

```
[{attr_1: value_1}, {attr_2: value_2}, {attr_3: value_3}, ...]
```

or

```
att_values = {first: second for first, second in zip(cells[::2], cells[1::2])}

# or:
# att_values = dict( zip(cells[::2], cells[1::2]) )
```

to get dictionary

```
{attr_1: value_1, attr_2: value_2, attr_3: value_3, ...}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. Although I do not understand the att_values = line that generates the dictionary.

Comment: @merlin , let say we have list `l = ['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3]`... `zip(l[::2], l[1::2])` generates for us tuples `('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)`. `[::2]` means *give us all **even** elements from list*, `[1::2]` - *give us all **odd** elements*. And we just making key-values from 2 values of each tuple: `{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
for row in response.css('section#attributes table tr'):
    td1 = row.xpath('.//td[1]/text()').get()
    td2 = row.xpath('.//td[2]/text()').get()
    # your logic further
```